# Adding Bullets to StringBuilder C#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I am using string builder to display error messages to my website. Is there a way to add bullet points to string builder? ul li.....

Is string builder the best way to display multiple error messages? I can not use the validation summary it doesn't allow me to check with what I am needing to check for.

Comment: `StringBuilder` has nothing to do with **html** markup. You need to provide *much* more context of your web app.

Comment: This is wrong on many levels

Comment: What you asked for but probably not what you want: `stringBuilder.Append("•")`

Comment: Why can't you just `stringBuilder.Append("<ul><li>"+myError+"</li></ul>");`?

Comment: Use array of string and display it as list items in website

Comment: @codeFinatic Is this a web app or desktop application?

Answer (score 1):

To maintain separation of concerns, I would prefer, not to tie error message preparation and their styling. It would be better, if you prepare the error messages in code behind but handle the display(including styling etc.) in the UI layer, perhaps using JavaScript/jQuery for Web applications.

However, for web application you may try following alternatives too, if you still want to keep the aspects together:

1) If the css style for bullet is available for you, you can create error messages like:

```
stringBuilder.Append("<div class='bullet'>"+ errorMessage +"</div>");
```

2) You can use html's in built list markup:

```
stringBuilder.Append("<ul style='list-style-type:circle'><li>"+ errorMessage +"</li></ul>");
```

You can learn more on html list markup [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp)

3) Though I am quite not sure, if this work for all situations, you can even use [html code :  &#8226](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

```
stringBuilder.Append("<div><span>&#8226</span>"+ errorMessage +"</div>");
```

Comment: HTML numeric character entity references are Unicode, not ASCII.